# Column sorting on lightning:datatable only sorting one way?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm trying to implement the sorting functionality on a lightning:datatable. Sorting works one way (descending, clicking the column header again and nothing happens). I have followed the documentation and here's my code below:

```
<aura:attribute name="selectedAccountId" type="Id" access="public" />
<aura:attribute name="accounts" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="mycolumns" type="List"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.doInit }"/>

<aura:registerEvent name="AccountFilterChange" type="c:AccountFilterChange" />


<lightning:datatable aura:id="lightningTable"
                     data="{! v.accounts }"
                     columns="{! v.mycolumns }"
                     keyField="Id"
                     onrowaction="{! c.handleRowAction }"
                     onsort="{!c.updateColumnSorting}"
                     hideCheckboxColumn="true"
/>
```

Controller:

```
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
   helper.callServer(component, "c.getAccounts", function(response) {
       component.set("v.accounts", response);
       })
    component.set('v.mycolumns', [
        {type: "button", typeAttributes: {
            label: '',
            iconName: 'utility:add',
            name: 'selectRecord',
            title: 'selectRecord',
            disabled: false,
            value: 'edit',
            variant: {fieldName: 'variantValue'},
        }},
        {label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text', sortable: true},
            ]);
        },

handleRowAction: function(component, event, helper) {
    var account = event.getParam("row")
    var action = event.getParam("action");
    if (action.name == "selectRecord") {
        var event = component.getEvent("AccountFilterChange");
         event.setParams({
            accountId: account.Id,
        });
    }
 event.fire();
 helper.addRow(component, account);
},

updateColumnSorting: function(component, event, helper) {
    var fieldName = event.getParam('fieldName');
    var sortDirection = event.getParam('sortDirection');
    // assign the latest attribute with the sorted column fieldName and sorted direction
    component.set("v.sortedBy", fieldName);
    component.set("v.sortedDirection", sortDirection);
    helper.sortData(component, fieldName, sortDirection);
    }
```

Helper:

```
sortData: function (component, fieldName, sortDirection) {
     var data = component.get("v.accounts");
     var reverse = sortDirection !== 'asc';
     //sorts the rows based on the column header that's clicked
     data.sort(this.sortBy(fieldName, reverse))
     component.set("v.accounts", data);
     },
 sortBy: function (field, reverse, primer) {
     var key = primer ? function(x) {return primer(x[field])} : function(x) {return x[field]};
     //checks if the two rows should switch places
     reverse = !reverse ? 1 : -1;
     return function (a, b) {
         return a = key(a), b = key(b), reverse * ((a > b) - (b > a));
     }
 }
```

How would I make this work so both desc/asc will work when clicking the column header?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One bit the documentation omits is that in order to get sorting to work, you have to bind a couple of extra attributes to the lightning:datatable. I've discovered this before quite by accident.

## Component/Application

```
<aura:attribute name="sortedBy"
                type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="sortedDirection"
                type="Boolean"
                default="true" />
```

...

```
<lightning:datatable ...                          
                     sortedBy="{!v.sortedBy}"
                     sortedDirection="{!v.sortedDirection}" />
```

Then, in your sortData function:

```
    component.set("v.sortedBy", event.getParam("fieldName"));
    component.set("v.sortedDirection", event.getParam("sortDirection"));
```

Once you do this, the rest of the code from the documentation should work as expected.

Comment: yes, I finally found the documentation for the properties on the Specification tab once you said this - but it certainly isn't expanded upon in the actual Documentation tab, like most of the other features are explained